# Using powershell, how to get a list of users per active directory group?

Tags: powershell, export

I am trying to export a list (.csv) with all the Active Directory groups beginning with "AD-Group-Mailbox*" in one column and the corresponding nested users per group in another column.

So far, I've managed to export a list of users only for a single group:

```
Get-ADGroupMember AD-Group-Mailbox-Parking | sort name | select name
```

But I can't understand how to do the same export at once for all the ad-groups beginning with "AD-Group-Mailbox*". There are over 200+ and I try to avoid doing every single export manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variant:

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter '(Name -like "AD-Group-Mailbox-*")' | 
    ForEach-Object { Get-ADGroupMember -Recursive -Identity $_ } |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'Name' |
    Sort-Object -Unique
```